# Is it required to register an app to use Key Vault to store secrets?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I have a .NET application that is currently running locally which accesses a database. The database secrets are stored in the appsettings.json file. My question is it possible to use keyvault **without** registering an application on Azure. If I should register an application, is it **free** or does it have a **monthly cost** . NOTE that I am currently on an AZURE FREE SUBSCRIPTION but will have to use KeyVault also for the future. Will this process of storing data into KeyVault and loading them again into the program costly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a little confusing at first - ultimately, what you need is a service principal. You can get one in a couple of ways:

1. Create an Enterprise Application or App Registration. This is a little more involved because you have to create it, then you have to manage secrets associated with it, and your app service would need to that registration's application/client ID and the current secret injected into its environment.
2. Turn on system-assigned managed identity in the app service configuration. This is the easiest way to go, because Azure takes care of everything - the registration and the secret management, injecting the current credential into your app's environment - automatically.
3. Create a managed identity in the Azure portal, and then configure your app to use it as a user-assigned managed identity. This is similar to #2, but the extra step allows you to create an identity that can be shared across multiple apps, if that's something you want.

This functionality all comes with the Azure Active Directory tenant you get as part of your free subscription. **There's a limit to this** - you can only integrate **10 web applications** with the free tier of Azure AD, beyond which you would need to upgrade to a paid tier.

**Edit:** It's possible that this 10 app limitation has been lifted since the last time I encountered it, but it would be a good thing to verify if you need to implement more than 10 apps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If I use the first way by creating an app registration will I be able to access the secrets from KeyVault to my local environment or I should be in production. I only have a console application running locally currently and I just want to replace the values in appsettings.json with the values stored in KeyVault. Basically I want to use Use Application ID and X.509 certificate for non-Azure-hosted apps to use key vault. Will that do the job ? One final question, registering an app to azure is it free or has a cost ?

Comment: Can you please tell me if it is necessary to host an application on Azure in order to use key vault ? I still don't know if it is possible to use it locally.

Comment: It's not required for an application to be on Azure to use Key Vault. There are two means of authenticating against it - if your on-premise Active Directory is synchronized with Azure Active Directory for your Azure tenant, you can directly authenticate from your apps using the `Microsoft.Identity` package and `DefaultAzureCredential`. If not, you'd need to store a client ID and secret locally to authenticate, which is perhaps a bit outside the scope of your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please tell me how to check if my on-premise Active Directory is synchronized with Azure Active Directory and if that is the case, what is the code needed to authenticate my console app to use microsoft identity to access key vault ?

Comment: For the time being I registered an app on Azure Active Directory to be a service principle to access key vault but in this case I should need a client and secret ID. I don't know if that was necessary because my application is currently running locally and I just need to use key vault locally. How can I use Microsoft.Identity in this case ?

Comment: You'd pass an instance of `ClientSecretCredential` and give its constructor the client ID and secret. Alternatively, if there are environment variables named `AZURE_TENANT_ID`, `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`, and `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`, then `DefaultAzureCredential` will work - however, this leaves the secret exposed in the environment of your on-premise application's session, which is perhaps undesirable.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure your Visual Studio to work with the key vault on your local environment. There are different ways to do it, but one of the ways is given in the link here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service.

You will require an Azure subscription first then you can to register application to Azure.